# Should we do anything about this question?

Tags: discussion

This was migrated from Writers:

[Can a 5'2" woman fit into a double bass' hard case?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/65514/can-a-52-woman-fit-into-a-double-bass-hard-case)

I can see why it was migrated from Writers, and why it was migrated here, but it seems to be off-topic here in the same way it was off-topic there. Normally, a question like this might fit better at World Building, I think.

It doesn't feel like throwing it back to Writers make sense. Is it bad enough here that we should do something with it, or better to just leave it alone?

Comment: If we close it here, it goes back to writers. I'm not sure what happens if it is migrated again (since the original migration is rejected as the question is closed, but a new migration opens up). Either way it 100% doesn't belong here.

Comment: I closed it a few minutes ago - Writers get to see if there is another destination for it... Personally I think Writers is the best place.

Comment: @DrMayhem It looks like it was answered on Writers before it was even migrated. But I can see the Writers community saying it is not a question about the process of writing any more than it's a question about music theory or practice. Maybe they'll close it there and SE will be happy and the asker will be happy since they did get their answer.

Comment: It was a question that could very likely be better answered by a musician than a writer.  So why not help them out?